# Networking within ScreenSaver in Swift

Tags: macos, swift, screensaver

So I've already made "static" screen savers in Swift, and I was wondering if it was possible to leverage an API while running the screensaver. If so, would it be any different than regular networking, since the computer might of shut off certain features while on a screen saver?

Comment: I think it would be possible, try it out or read the docs

Comment: I can't find anything in the docs...I'm asking for more detail on the topic @Kametrixom